Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0' requires version 34 or later to compile
How to know a particular version of dependency can be compiled with a minimum/maximum version of Android SDK API version.
e.g. How to know Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0' will be compiled with minimum and maximum version of Android SDK version.
The error I am seeing in the logcat is given below.

Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.7.0' requires
libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against
version 34 or later of the Android APIs.
:app is currently compiled against android-33.
Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
plugin 7.4.1 is 33.
Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android
Gradle plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).

Note: I can't update the compileSdkVerion to 34. I have to modify(downgrade) the version of dependency so that the project gets built successfully. Thay's why it's important to know a particular version of dependency is compiled with minimum/maximum version of Android SDK version. So, where do I go to find out the mapping relationship between a dependency version and Android version?
Any link or lead would be appreciated.
Thank you in Advance! :)

What makes you think you can't update to compileSdkVersion 34? You should always be compiling with the latest SDK, even if you don't target the latest SDK (which is what actually changes your behavior, as per this blog post).
